# Barely usable after hardware upgrade (without reinstalling Ubuntu)

Tags: drivers, nvidia, upgrade, hardware

Today I performed a hardware upgrade (ASRock B450M Pro4, Ryzen 5 3600, 2x16GB DDR4-3200. Kept my GTX770 and SSD for now) without reinstalling Ubuntu and now even scrolling websites is lagging severely.

I ran an apt update/upgrade and reinstalled the newest Nvidia driver. I also found the suggestion to run `sudo update-initramfs -u -kall` somewhere but that didn't change anything.
On Windows (same SSD) everything works fine so far, so it shouldn't be a problem with the hardware I assume.

Any ideas what else I can try besides reinstalling Ubuntu?

**Edit: Commands I ran according to comments here**

`nvidia-settings`: shows GPU but also

```
(nvidia-settings:6274): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 10:00:41.408: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
** Message: 10:00:41.661: PRIME: No offloading required. Abort
** Message: 10:00:41.661: PRIME: is it supported? no
```

`lsmod | grep nvidia`

```
nvidia_uvm           1011712  0
nvidia_drm             53248  3
nvidia_modeset       1228800  5 nvidia_drm
nvidia              34091008  178 nvidia_uvm,nvidia_modeset
drm_kms_helper        225280  1 nvidia_drm
drm                   565248  6 drm_kms_helper,nvidia_drm
```

`nvidia-smi`: lists my GPU and driver version but there are a couple N/A entries

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 460.39       Driver Version: 460.39       CUDA Version: 11.2     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 770     Off  | 00000000:06:00.0 N/A |                  N/A |
| 29%   29C    P8    N/A /  N/A |    180MiB /  1991MiB |     N/A      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|  No running processes found                                                 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

`inxi -f`

```
CPU:       Info: 6-Core model: AMD Ryzen 5 3600 bits: 64 type: MT MCP L2 cache: 3072 KiB 
           Speed: 2196 MHz min/max: 2200/3600 MHz Core speeds (MHz): 1: 2196 2: 2191 3: 2195 4: 2196 5: 2193 6: 2199 7: 2195 
           8: 2195 9: 2194 10: 2197 11: 2193 12: 2196 
           Flags: 3dnowprefetch abm adx aes aperfmperf apic arat avic avx avx2 bmi1 bmi2 bpext cat_l3 cdp_l3 clflush 
           clflushopt clwb clzero cmov cmp_legacy constant_tsc cpb cpuid cqm cqm_llc cqm_mbm_local cqm_mbm_total cqm_occup_llc 
           cr8_legacy cx16 cx8 de decodeassists extapic extd_apicid f16c flushbyasid fma fpu fsgsbase fxsr fxsr_opt ht 
           hw_pstate ibpb ibs irperf lahf_lm lbrv lm mba mca mce misalignsse mmx mmxext monitor movbe msr mtrr mwaitx 
           nonstop_tsc nopl npt nrip_save nx osvw overflow_recov pae pat pausefilter pclmulqdq pdpe1gb perfctr_core 
           perfctr_llc perfctr_nb pfthreshold pge pni popcnt pse pse36 rdpid rdpru rdrand rdseed rdt_a rdtscp rep_good sep sev 
           sha_ni skinit smap smca sme smep ssbd sse sse2 sse4_1 sse4_2 sse4a ssse3 stibp succor svm svm_lock syscall tce 
           topoext tsc tsc_scale umip v_vmsave_vmload vgif vmcb_clean vme vmmcall wbnoinvd wdt xgetbv1 xsave xsavec xsaveerptr 
           xsaveopt xsaves
```

Comment: More information would help us make reasonable suggestions. Have you checked the vendor for firmware updates? Please add the text output (use the code tags) of inxi -F

Comment: Try starting `nvidia-settings` to check if the NVidia driver is active at all, or if the system has fallen back to the Nouveau or even the framebuffer graphics driver.

Comment: I ran your suggested commands and added the output to the original question

Comment: We use a question and answer format on Ask Ubuntu.  If you have a solution, add an answer below.  Please don't edit your question and add your answer to the body of the question.  You can also come back in a few days and accept your own answer to let future visitors know that this question has a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Type `about:config` in the Firefox address bar, click the  <kbd>Accept the Risk and Continue</kbd>  button to continue, and toggle `layers.acceleration.force-enabled` from `false` to `true`.